# Windows Store App purchase customer information

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have a Windows Store app and I want to build a website for it, but how will I know who has purchased my app from the Windows 8 app store?

My app doesn't do in-app purchases, I don't use any other 3rd party payment systems. I only use the Windows Store and so I'm not sure. I understand that we are limited to what kinds of information is revealed to us, but if, for example, my website offers extra services that they can signup for on my website and login to use, for paying users, how am I to know that they have purchased my app? I don't see any relevant API's or anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [isActive property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.licenseinformation.isactive.aspx) on the LicenseInformation class to tell if your app has been purchased.

Comment: after viewing your link, I remember being on that page before. Dunno what happened though. Thank you :)